# DataTable is not pushing data correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

My dataTable columns configuration options:

```
"columns": [{
    "name": "id",
    "data": "id",
    "visible": false,
    "orderable": false
  }, {
    "name": "tblOpr",
    "title": "<div class='table-opr-col table-opr-col-head'><div class='tbl-opr edit-opr-col-head'><span>Edit</span></div></div>",
    "visible": true,
    "orderable": false
  }, {
    "title": "Employee",
    "data": "emp_name",
    "orderable": true,
    "name": "emp_name"
  }, {
    "title": "Date",
    "data": "date",
    "orderable": true,
    "name": "date"
  }, {
    "title": "In Time",
    "data": "in_time",
    "orderable": true,
    "name": "in_time"
  }, {
    "title": "Out Time",
    "data": "out_time",
    "orderable": true,
    "name": "out_time"
  }, {
    "title": "In Deficit",
    "data": "in_deficit",
    "orderable": true,
    "name": "in_deficit"
  }, {
    "title": "Out Deficit",
    "data": "out_deficit",
    "orderable": true,
    "name": "out_deficit"
  }, {
    "title": "Hours worked",
    "data": "wt",
    "orderable": true,
    "name": "wt"
  }]
```

Server side is true.
The data from server is:

```
{
  "recordsTotal": 10,
  "recordsFiltered": 10,
  "data": [{
    "id": "92",
    "emp_name": "Anish Gupta (10012)",
    "date": "2017-09-15",
    "in_time": "22:10:00",
    "out_time": "00:00:00",
    "in_deficit": "00:10:00",
    "out_deficit": "",
    "wt": "00:00:00"
  }, {
    "id": "46",
    "emp_name": "Raman Kumar (10010)",
    "date": "2017-09-15",
    "in_time": "21:39:00",
    "out_time": "00:00:00",
    "in_deficit": "-00:21:00",
    "out_deficit": "",
    "wt": "00:00:00"
  }, {
    "id": "91",
    "emp_name": "Anish Gupta (10012)",
    "date": "2017-09-14",
    "in_time": "22:43:00",
    "out_time": "07:21:00",
    "in_deficit": "00:43:00",
    "out_deficit": "-00:21:00",
    "wt": "08:38:00"
  }, {
    "id": "45",
    "emp_name": "Raman Kumar (10010)",
    "date": "2017-09-14",
    "in_time": "21:10:00",
    "out_time": "06:49:00",
    "in_deficit": "-00:50:00",
    "out_deficit": "00:11:00",
    "wt": "09:39:00"
  }, {
    "id": "90",
    "emp_name": "Anish Gupta (10012)",
    "date": "2017-09-13",
    "in_time": "22:30:00",
    "out_time": "07:41:00",
    "in_deficit": "00:30:00",
    "out_deficit": "-00:41:00",
    "wt": "09:11:00"
  }, {
    "id": "44",
    "emp_name": "Raman Kumar (10010)",
    "date": "2017-09-13",
    "in_time": "22:10:00",
    "out_time": "06:28:00",
    "in_deficit": "00:10:00",
    "out_deficit": "00:32:00",
    "wt": "08:18:00"
  }, {
    "id": "89",
    "emp_name": "Anish Gupta (10012)",
    "date": "2017-09-12",
    "in_time": "00:00:00",
    "out_time": "00:00:00",
    "in_deficit": "",
    "out_deficit": "",
    "wt": "00:00:00"
  }, {
    "id": "43",
    "emp_name": "Raman Kumar (10010)",
    "date": "2017-09-12",
    "in_time": "00:00:00",
    "out_time": "00:00:00",
    "in_deficit": "",
    "out_deficit": "",
    "wt": "00:00:00"
  }, {
    "id": "88",
    "emp_name": "Anish Gupta (10012)",
    "date": "2017-09-11",
    "in_time": "21:10:00",
    "out_time": "06:28:00",
    "in_deficit": "-00:50:00",
    "out_deficit": "00:32:00",
    "wt": "09:18:00"
  }, {
    "id": "42",
    "emp_name": "Raman Kumar (10010)",
    "date": "2017-09-11",
    "in_time": "22:30:00",
    "out_time": "07:10:00",
    "in_deficit": "00:30:00",
    "out_deficit": "-00:10:00",
    "wt": "08:40:00"
  }],
  "draw": 2
}
```

The `tblOpr` columns data is being pushed from client side, so do not worry about that column data.
But my datatable is pushing the data on wrong index. It is skipping 3 columns from starting.

[image]

You can  see in this screenshot. In `time` columns data is going in `Edit` column, `out time` columns data is going in `employee` column...in the same way last columns ours worked columns data is going in going in out time column.

If anybody has any idea about this please reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't mentioned how you pass the data to DataTables...

In this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/LzpLmK?editors=1010), I assumed you do: `"data":json.data`, where `json` is the variable name I used in my example to hold the data you posted.

Then, the problem you have is 9 columns but only 8 data for them.
You have to tell to DataTables what to do with the extra column not having data.

I assumed this was the "Edit" column.

```
"data": null,
"defaultContent": "<button>Click!</button>",
```

`"data": null` is quite self explanatory. Then you have to provide some content for that column. Here, I just added a button.